# follow path from specific point not working

Tags: constraints

i have an animation of 300 frames
frames 1 - 50 a sphere moves from the center of a circle to the perimeter
frames 51 - 110 = 1 complete rotation
frames 111 - 170 = another complete rotation
frames 171 - 230 = a third rotation
frames 231 - 290 = final rotation

as you can see. the blue dotted line is moving but sphere remains stationary.

i have added a file if some can please provide some insight it would be greatly apprectiated

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ve clicked on the constraint *Animated Path* button, which has created a modifier for the curve and will cumulate with the keyframes that you’ve created on the *Offset*, are you sure that you want that? If not, select the curve, go into the *Graph Editor* and in the *N panel > Modifiers* > remove the *Generator* modifier.

The *Forward Axis* of the sphere’s *Follow Path* constraint is currently -Z, it won’t make the sphere move, choose X or Y.

As the existing keyframes for the sphere probably won’t work corectly anymore, remove them, put the sphere back to the center of the scene (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>) and create your new *Offset* keyframes. To go from the center to the periphery you can keyframe the *Influence* value.